# Is there a way to read an reply of a mail using Gmail API

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

```
foreach (var part in emailInfoResponse.Result.Payload.Parts)
{
    if (part.Parts != null)
        foreach (var innerPart in part.Parts)
        {
            if (innerPart.MimeType == "text/plain")
            {
              body = innerPart.Body.Data;
            }
        }
}
```

I am successfully reading the body ONLY of the main mail. It is not taking the data from the reply messages assigned to the mail,
any ideas how I can I read the replies to the mail too? Or even if there is a way to take only the replies of a specific mail

Comment: Are you reading the sent messages to pick up replies? or you want to de-segment any individual mail in the layers of responses?

Comment: main mail will have data about person and with every single reply to this mail, the data about the person is changed, so if I can count the replies and separate them from each other will be much easier for me to parse the data from the mail, but the strange thing is that I am seeing the data only from the main mail at the moment. I am not able to read the body of the replies

Comment: Confused ... you have a mail and now you want to read the reply to _that_ mail? _OR_ You have a Mail, which _is_ a reply to another mail and want to read both??

Comment: Fildor I will give you example: in the main body there is a text like: Michael Jackson 01, there will be a reply to this mail but the data can be Michael Jackson 02 and there is no limit to the replies, so I need to find a way to read and count the replies, because I need to take the data from every single reply + the data from the main

Comment: the problem is say Ann Other replies, but she then edits the previous mail data to add comments and highlight it in colours you wont be picking that up as her email.. Of course then theres also the issue not everyone uses the same format for replies.. and previous mail indents

Comment: Ok, I'm leaning out the window right now, but I have some doubts "Email" is a viable means of doing what you are doing. Without knowing the gmail-api, I doubt the "root" mail "knows" it has been replied to. The reply mail may "know" which one it is the reply of ... but I wouldn't rely on the reply containing the original. Could you tell us a bit more about what you are trying to solve and why you chose email as your preferred data exchange tool?

Comment: @Fildor, the client was using his gmail for storing data. They have mails which subject is a company name and in the main body there are names of clients of the specific company, in replies there are clients which have been added in time. So in order to move the data from the mails to the database I need to be able to read the replies. So this is basically a console app (migration tool in this case, which will be executed only once) for reading a large number of mails and create records in the database.

Comment: Have you already tried to use the Thread? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads

Comment: @tehhowch, yes. I started to search is it possible the reply of an mail to have different id as a thread/mail

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping you can simply switch to something else. But your task is to address that exact issue. Tough one, really.

Comment: It sounds like a combination of thread parsing and also merging  based on message subject (in case the "reply" is in a different conversation) will solve your issue. Basically loop all threads in the relevant mailbox, parse the data into a list based on the subject, and then add to that list if other threads have the same subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get later / other messages in a conversation, you need to retrieve the source thread:

```
String threadID = emailInfoResponse.Result.ThreadId;
Thread thread = service.Users.Threads.Get(userID, threadID).Execute();
foreach( var msg in thread.Messages )
{
    /* your code for each message */
}
```

Per the [Gmail message reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages), messages can share a threadId if they have both the correct headers and the same subject. Otherwise, they will be on different email threads.

You'd probably want to refactor a bit and start from a [`ThreadList`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1UsersResource_1_1ThreadsResource_1_1ListRequest.html). This way, you can find all conversations that match a specific input query (to find only the messages that correspond to these client lists):

1. Make data storage object: `Dictionary<String, Container>`, where the string is the company (from the email subject, or wherever), and the container probably only needs unique values so `HashSet` or similar.
2. Page through the ThreadList
3. For each thread
4. Page through messages
5. For each message, if the first message, get the subject i.e. company name (all messages have to share a subject in the same thread).
6. Then append the clients to the data storage object based on the subject (company name).
7. Construct your database records from the data storage object as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MimeKit.MimeMessage Reply(MimeKit.MimeMessage message, bool replyToAll)
{
 var reply = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
 if (message.ReplyTo.Count > 0)
  {
   reply.To.AddRange(message.ReplyTo);
  }
 else if (message.From.Count > 0)
  {
  reply.To.AddRange(message.From);
  }
  else if (message.Sender != null)
  {
  reply.To.Add(message.Sender);
  }
  if (replyToAll)
  {
  reply.To.AddRange(message.To);
  reply.Cc.AddRange(message.Cc);
  }
  if (!message.Subject.StartsWith("Re:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    reply.Subject = "Re:" + message.Subject;
  else
    reply.Subject = message.Subject;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.MessageId))
  {
    reply.InReplyTo = message.MessageId;
    foreach (var id in message.References)
      reply.References.Add(id);
      reply.References.Add(message.MessageId);
  }
  using (var quoted = new StringWriter())
  {
    var sender = message.Sender ?? message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault();
    quoted.WriteLine("On {0}, {1} wrote:", message.Date.ToString("f"), !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender.Name) ? sender.Name : sender.Address);
    using (var reader = new StringReader(message.TextBody))
    {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        quoted.Write("> ");
        quoted.WriteLine(line);
      }
    }
    reply.Body = new MimeKit.TextPart("plain")
    {
      Text = quoted.ToString()
    };
  }
  return reply;
}
```